# Need to do an incremental load using ADF. Source is a csv from ADLS and Sink is Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to do an incremental data load to Azure sql from csv files in ADLS through ADF. The problem I am facing is Azure SQL would generate the primary key column (ID) and the data would be inserted to Azure SQl. But when the pipeline is re triggered the data would be duplicated again. So how do I handle these duplicates ? Because only incremental load should be updated everytime but since primary key column is generated by SQL there would be duplicates every run. Please help !!

Comment: Can you please provide information about what you have tried like pipeline flow, activity configurations? Also try to provide sample example data input and output that you are getting and expected output.

Comment: I have data flow activities that would map the data based on the source data. So a csv file is generated with all the mapping. This csv is inserted to Azure sql using copy activity finally.

Comment: Is the primary key column auto generated by SQL table?

Comment: The question is vague without any important details that can help answering the question . But based on assumptions, I believe you have used Sequence to generate primary key. Can you try using a hash function like md5 or sha2 to generate primary key which will always produce the same hash based on the columns you have? Also, you can use the upsert method in copy activity based on the primary key to avoid duplicates

Comment: But upsert method would reinsert the same data again as primary key is generated by SQL only.

Comment: You will need to have a primary key to load data incrementally in both source and sink. If there is no key column in source data, then you can't use a key column to upsert.

Comment: Please provide information about how the csv file data and the SQL table data looks like (sample)

Comment: You can then try using MERGE statement in a stored procedure to upsert instead of copy activity. Without any sample data or even some more details, its very difficult to understand the question. Can you provide more details on what exactly you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

> You can consider comparing source and sink data first by excluding
> Primary key column and then filter that rows which modified and take
> it to sink table.

In below video I created a hash on top of few columns from source and sink and compared them to identify changed data. Same way you can consider checking the changed data first and then load it to sink table.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2PkwNqxj1E